# How to disable multiple line select Bokeh DataTable

Tags: python, bokeh

How can I make the datatable widget support only single line selection? (disable multiple line select).

Comment: Refering to http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.tables.html , selectable attr can disable or enable Multiple selection. but not sure how to implement one line selection

Comment: Yeah, I have seen this. Thanks @Shijo. As you noted, this doesn't explain how to enable ONLY one line selection

Comment: It's a bug, the functionality was never implemented https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9327

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a hack/workaround using events

```
import functools

def table_select_callback(source, attrname, old, new):
    # the lists of indicies are in random order, sort them
    new = sorted(new)
    old = sorted(old)

    if len(new) == 0:
        # they selected 0 elements, return
        return

    elif len(new) == 1:
        # they selected 1 element, return
        return

    elif len(old) == 0:
        # this shouldn't be possible but it's JS. #YOLO
        source.selected.indices = [new[0]]

    source.selected.indices = [new[0]] if old[0] != new[0] else [new[-1]]


# table_source is your instance of ColumnDataSource or equiv
table_source.selected.on_change(
    "indices",
    functools.partial(
        table_select_callback, table_source
    ),
)
```